# Turning on lamp pauses sound in my headset

Tags: windows, audio, headset, voltage, interference

I have my headset connected to my PC with USB. When I turn on my lamp on my table (fluorescent) the music from my headset pauses for about a second while the lamp powers up. Then it's back to normal. The lamp is connected to the same power outlet as the computer.

Two times I even had to plug my headset in and out again because Windows "couldn't recognize it".

I reckon this has something to do with voltage? :s No idea what's going on. Would appreciate if someone could explain to me what's going on. I'm happy to share more information if that's needed to understand what could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I have never measured it, but one of the things that a florescent light does when it turns on is the initial arc, or startup method or glowing filiments at the ends of the arc.  This initial startup for it takes a momentary large burst of power.
The burst of initial power has been stated to be so high that a florescent lighting is not "efficient" until it has been on for a short while.

Also there is a lot of interferance from a light of that type.

All of the above completly differs depending on the type of curcuits, start type, type of bulb and so many factors that even if I knew the exact model, I would not guess at how much power that would be.

The modern PC power supply has caps (power storage and cleanup) that can usually keep any very short burst  like that from causing problems.  Poor quality and older power supplies more likely to be effected from any short change in voltage from the wall plug.

Also you have interferance possibilities, the headphones wiring acting as antenna , any poor shielding , and a small burst of airborn energy.
If the audio device is a bluetooth type of connection, it woud be very typical that the data stream could have glitched , from interferance , and restarted, taking a bit of time to resend packets , fill buffers and all.

If it was either of the above things you could test for them.
For interferance, leave the lamp on the same plug and test with it further away from the computer and any extended wiring from the computer (IE the headsets).

For the power surge  Power the lamp from a completly different wiring curcuit of the house (socket to the main curcuit box). A Different room sometimes, different sections of the house, then you could run a extention (temporarily) to put it in the exact same place, and see if it still did it.

To add more information, was it Wireless type?  What is the Computer model? The PSU type?  What is the model of the USB audio device? And what is the lamp item or bulb type?

Answer (score 2):

Psycogeek's suggestions are good ones.  Also, check the grounding of the lamp and the PC.
I once had a problem that surge current on startup of a device (not a lamp) traveled through the safety ground rather than through the neutral.  The device was connected by USB to a PC, so some of the surge went down the shell of the USB cable and knocked the device off the USB bus for a second.  Check whether both the lamp and the PC are properly safety-grounded, and whether the polarity is reversed on one of your AC outlets.